# best way save data 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, filesize

i've a problem about saving 2d array's value to hardisk. i build 5000x5000 item similarity table (float) and i want to store it because it will be continuesly used. i've tried save them to .txt file by format index1,index2,value+\n and they're growing to 250MB of size (its approx 25million of rows). is there any ways to reduce its size?
i would be glad if anyone mind to help me

Comment: Store the data in a binary format. A float takes 4 bytes, and with 25 million values, that results in a 100MB file (or a 95.4MiB file). Look at `java.io.DataOutputStream`. You can also run the output through a `GZIPOutputStream` if you're concerned about storage. Also, why would you output index1 and index2? Just output the values in column, then row, order.

Comment: Please provide some more info. What have you tried so far? Zip? non-txt format? How are the floats distributed (maybe lots of them are 0, maybe only a few of them have digits, maybe there are areas (eg the top left 100x100 cells) that have the same values?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt actualy i'm still newbie at programming and lack of knowledge how to modeling somethig. i save index1 and index2 so while i read line by line i can put its value direct position on 2d array, just like array[index1][index2]=value; i will try your advice store to binary and i'll post the result here, thank you very much

Comment: @Stefan yes, i only store half because array[i][j] and array[j][i] have same value, if i dont do that the file will be 500mb. and about storing file format, i havent tried on mysql and its pretty annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of storing index of each cell i.e. index1 and index2, we can write the size of the matrix at the beginning of the file itself using 2 integers(number of rows & number of columns). Use this information while reading, to know when a row of the matrix is read completely.
2. Instead of writing string value of float, we can use `Float.floatToIntBits(float)` method to get IEEE-754 representation as an integer and serialize the integer as 4 bytes

This will reduce the size of a 5000 x 5000 matrix to ~ 100MB

Comment: i haven't tried that. i will try your advice. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Map<Float, List<Float>>
```

type

As @Satish said, it will requires 5000*5000*4(bytes for float type) = 100,000,000 Bytes or 100000 KB or 100 MB minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Is the array sparsely populated, you could consider only saving the data points that actually have values. Then a `Map` keyed by the x/y coordinate could reduce the size considerably.

Otherwise, dealing with 100-250 MB files can be a little arduous. Why not use some sort of database persistence? There are plenty of SQL or no-SQL databases that can optimise the storage operations for you.

Comment: ah, i have tried on mysql, but its take a long time

Comment: Have a read about NoSQL databases https://www.networkworld.com/article/2991969/big-data-business-intelligence/which-nosql-database-is-right-for-you.html

Answer (score 0):

finaly I've tried to store them on binary format by using ObjectOutputStream then the file reduce to 100mb. i found this tutorial [here](https://www.java-forums.org/blogs/fatabass/784-writing-array-object-binary-file-reading-back.html), it works as i expected. and it also can save RAM consumption. Thank you very much :)